# AttributeError: Array instance has no attribute '__trunc__'

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 2D-arrays in python using c-types. For that I have created two modules arrays.py and array2D.py

TraceBack is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\array2D.py", line 52, in <module>

 arr = Array2D(2,4)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\array2D.py", line 15, in __init__

 self._theRows[i] = arrays.Array( numCols )

File "C:\Python27\Lib\arrays.py", line 37, in __setitem__

self._elements[ index ] = value

AttributeError: Array instance has no attribute '__trunc__'
```

**Code**

**arrays.py module**

```
import ctypes

class Array:

#Creates an array with size elements.
def __init__( self, size ):
    assert size > 0, "Array size must be > 0"
    self._size = size
    print "sixe is %s" %self._size

 # Create the array structure using the ctypes module.
    PyArrayType = ctypes.c_int * size
    self._elements = PyArrayType()
    print "type is e", type(self._elements)
   #self._elements = ctypes.c_int * size


# Initialize each element.
    #for i in range(self._size):
    #self.clear( i )


# Returns the size of the array.
def __len__( self ):
    return self._size

# Gets the contents of the index element.
def __getitem__( self, index ):
    assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
    return self._elements[ index ]

# Puts the value in the array element at index position.
 def __setitem__( self, index, value ):
     assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
     print "Type is ", type(index)
     f._index = (index)
     self._elements[ index ] = value


 # Clears the array by setting each element to the given value.
  def clear( self, value ):
      for i in range( len(self) ) :
          self._elements[i] = value
```

**array2D.py**

```
import arrays


class Array2D :
# Creates a 2-D array of size numRows x numCols.
    def __init__( self, numRows, numCols ):

 # Create a 1-D array to store an array reference for each row.
        self._theRows = arrays.Array( numRows )

# Create the 1-D arrays for each row of the 2-D array.
    for i in range( numRows ) :
        self._theRows[i] = arrays.Array( numCols )

# Returns the number of rows in the 2-D array.
    def numRows( self ):
        return len( self._theRows )

# Returns the number of columns in the 2-D array.
    def numCols( self ):
        return len( self._theRows[0] )

 # Clears the array by setting every element to the given value.
    def clear( self, value ):
        for row in range( self.numRows() ):
            row.clear( value )

# Gets the contents of the element at position [i, j]
    def __getitem__( self, ndxTuple ):
        assert len(ndxTuple) == 2, "Invalid number of array subscripts."
        row = ndxTuple[0]
        col = ndxTuple[1]
        assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
            and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
            "Array subscript out of range."
        the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
        return the1dArray[col]


# Sets the contents of the element at position [i,j] to value.
    def __setitem__( self, ndxTuple, value ):
        assert len(ndxTuple) == 3, "Invalid number of array subscripts."
        row = ndxTuple[0]
        col = ndxTuple[1]
        assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
        and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
            "Array subscript out of range."
        the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
        the1dArray[col] = value


Forming the 2d array using the following line

arr = Array2D(2,4)

print "arr is %s" %arr
```

Can anyone please let me know what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not a good idea to put your own modules into the folder where Python standard library is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that here you try to store an `Array` instance into an array that accepts `ctypes.c_int` instances:

```
 # Create a 1-D array to store an array reference for each row.
        self._theRows = arrays.Array( numRows )

# Create the 1-D arrays for each row of the 2-D array.
    for i in range( numRows ) :
        self._theRows[i] = arrays.Array( numCols )
```

Comment: Thank You for pointing that out Janne. It is working if I change the array type from ctypes.c_int to ctypes_py_object. But, I would also like to know what does the error "no attribute 'trunc'" has to do with this. Can you please share if you have any idea on this?

Comment: @user2260089 `__trunc__` is used by `math.trunc` and is one way of trying to coerce an object into an integer. I could not reproduce the exact error because the code you posted does not run.